# gorm: json of json not work

Tags: mysql, json, go, marshalling, go-gorm

Sample:

```
{
  "id": 1
  "data": {"1": 2}
}
```

Struct definition:

```
type Item struct {
  id int `json:"id"`
  data interface{} `json:"data"`
}
```

I need to parse the payload from a http post, so I used `interface{}` for `data`, `json.Unmarshal()` is successful, but gorm produces error while calling `db.Create(item)`:

```
(sql: converting Exec argument #5's type: unsupported type map[string]interface {}, a map)
```

Instead, I change from `interface{}` to `string`, calling `json.Unmarshal()` to parse json POST payload produces error.

```
unmarshal type error: expected=string, got=object
```

Basically, one requires `interface{}`, one requires `string`.

Anyone encountered this?

Comment: First of all, **how does it not work?** What's breaking? Second, I'm not a Go expert -- but wouldn't it make more sense that the second annotation read `json:"data"`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If this is working with a pre-existing database, is there any chance that there's a type conflict between the `data` field and the corresponding database field?

Comment: `gorm` is an ORM, so the schema is defined on the fly (in this case `db.CreateTable` and `db.AutoMigrate`). I think this is a feature that `gorm` not implemented yet. I found a work around that uses 2 struct; one uses `string` for `json.Unmarshal()` part, then copy each field of this struct to another struct that uses `interface{}`; but it looks rather messy when `Item` has lots of fields. So, I want to know if anyone have better idea.

Comment: Try to change the type from `interface{}` to `json.RawMessage`, if you sure its a json.

Comment: It got similar error while calling `db.Create(item)`: `(sql: converting Exec argument #5's type: unsupported type json.RawMessage, a slice)`

Comment: Is your `"data": {1: 2}` field contain non string keys like what you've put in your question ? Try to have a look at this [link](http://blog.dubbelboer.com/2015/05/24/go-intmap-marshal.html)

Comment: Nice catch, my bad, it should contain only string key.

Comment: `json.RawMessage` is an alias for `[]byte` which [defines the JSON marshaller interface](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/stream.go?s=6218:6240#L237). You can implement an analogous type yourself based on `string`, whose `UnmarshalJSON` method casts its argument to a `string` instead of appending it to the invocant slice.

Comment: Thanks, I just implemented the same thing you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is defining a custom type that implements `sql.Valuer`, `sql.Scanner`, `json.Marshaler` and `json.Unmarshaler` interfaces. Sample of my implementation:

```golang
type Data string

func (t *Data) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(*t), nil
}

func (t *Data) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    *t = Data(data)
    return nil
}

func (t Data) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return string(t), nil
}

func (t *Data) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    s, ok := src.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return nil
    }
    *t = Data(s)
    return nil
}

// Data implements the below interfaces to satisfy both
// json parser and sql parser
var _ json.Marshaler = (*Data)(nil)
var _ json.Unmarshaler = (*Data)(nil)
var _ sql.Scanner = (*Data)(nil)
var _ driver.Valuer = (*Data)(nil)
```